# What is [1:] and sum(b'%a'%s)%34 in Python?

Tags: python, list, sum

Consider:

```
for s in[*open(i:=0)][1:]:i+=1;print(f'Case #{i}:',sum(b'%a'%s)%34)
```

I can't understand the above code... I searched and now I know that open(0) is the same as *sys.stdin* and `:=` is the [walrus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions), but what are `[1:]` and `sum(b'%a'%s)%34`, and how does this code work?

Comment: Well, it's terribly obfuscated is what it is…

Comment: I agree too.. it is short coding of coding quiz and I just wanna know just for learning purpose

Comment: Seems to be a code golf solution that opens a file, read its contents from the second line (the cases), convert each line to bytes and print the sum of those bytes as ints modded by 34. Without more context, this is just wild speculation.

Comment: `[1:]` is slice notation.  `b'%a'%s` is old-style string formatting.  `%34` is modulo division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more readable version:

```
for s in [*open(i:=0)][1:]:
    i += 1
    print(f'Case #{i}:', sum(b'%a' % s) % 34)
```

As you said, `open(0)` opens stdin to read from.
`[*open(0)]` unpacks all stdin input into a list, with one line per entry.
`i:=0` also initialises the variable `i` to `0` at the same time; this is just a code golfing shorthand.
[`[1:]` slices that list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/476) to omit the first line.

[The `%a` formatter converts lines using `ascii`:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

> [..] return a string containing a printable representation of an object, but escape the non-ASCII characters in the string returned by `repr()` using `\x`, `\u`, or `\U` escapes. This generates a string similar to that returned by `repr()` in Python 2.

```
>>> '%a' % 'foobar'
"'foobar'"
```

Using a `b''` string makes the result `bytes`.
`bytes` are really just sequences of integers (byte values).
`sum` sums that sequence of integers.
`% 34` mod-34s the result:

```
>>> sum(b'%a' % 'foobar')
711
>>> sum(b'%a' % 'foobar') % 34
31
```

---

So, this prints the 34-modded sum of the byte values of each line of input (except the first). Whatever that's good for…